# Using microdata for SEO will help to increase SERP Position?

Tags: seo, microdata, search-results, rich-snippets

Does really rich snippets (microdata) helps to increase the SERP position or it will be just for usability purpose?

if adding rich snippets to page helps, then how it will affects the SERP position?

Comment: You will also find many other questions and answers regarding Microdata and Rich Snippets SEO using the search function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, they do not ***directly*** influence your SERP position. However, they do increase CTR (click-through-rate) on search results. A lot of webmasters work hard at getting themselves into the top five results for a specific keyword without ever giving much thought to CTR. This is a bit wasteful, in my opinion, considering our sole reason for trying to rank well is to gain more traffic.

There is also a belief among many SEOs that CTR ***does*** affect your SERP rankings, which would make sense, considering how useful a metric it is.

Comment: Good answer here. Maybe you could modify it to fit the question marked as a duplicate too.